# Geometry nodes: How to count the number of distributed instances of index "1"

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to count the number of instances of index "1".. or "2".. ets..

But it returns just my input index

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your exact setup and how you get the value *Index*, so I've built an example here where randomly created points are assigned random values (in a range of $0$ - $10$), which then repeat more often.

If you then use these values as a base or as your *Index* (Wherever you take the value from), you can accumulate the occurrences of this value with the node `Accumulate Field`:

[image]

Comment: are you sure this works with index? i would have used e.g. the random value you put in the instance index node to compare with equal....isn't index always just once? like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVknw.png ...and works with float too ;)

Comment: @Chris The setup works as long as you pass (instead of index) a value that repeats. I don't know the setup, so it might be good to share the blend file. I tested it with a captured value (`Attribute Capture`).

Comment: maybe i misunderstood something...but AFAIK index will never repeat !? or am i wrong? else index wouldn't be an index...would it?

Comment: @Chris You are right, *Index* does not repeat. But I assume that here instead some value is queried that repeats.

Comment: ok...maybe you should change your answer....because he will built that as you did....and will fail ....and you will get maybe a downvote....i just want to prevent that ;) you can even copy my picture in there if you like...it works, i tested it ;)

Comment: @Chris Good point, modified the answer! Thanks!